# How to add 'courtesy' to reference the source in beamer slides?

Tags: beamer

What is the usually followed way to add 'courtesy' for images in Beamer? I have looked up a number of searches on the Internet but could not find a solution.

Comment: Hi, you can simply add some text `Coutesy of somebody` below the picture. Is your question about how to do it in LaTeX, or what to do in general?

Answer (score 7):

I'm sure this is not the 'usual' way, but I basically use this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter
\gdef\@imgsrcnavigation{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{%
  \makebox[\paperwidth]{%
    \hspace*{1.5em}
    \@imgsrcnavigation
    \hfill}%
}
\DeclareDocumentCommand \imgsrc { s O {Image credit} +m }{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \def\tempa{off}%
        \def\tempb{#3}%
        \ifx\tempa\tempb
          \gdef\@imgsrcnavigation{}%
        \else
          \gdef\@imgsrcnavigation{{\tiny #2:\thinspace #3}}%
        \fi
  }{%
        {\tiny #2:\thinspace #3}%
  }%
}
\defbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{dim byd}{%
  \parbox{\paperwidth}{%
        \hspace*{1.5em}%
        \@imgsrcnavigation
        \hfill\par\vskip .5em}}
\newcommand*\navigationoff{\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}[dim byd]{}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}

    \imgsrc{MWE package author}
  \end{frame}
  \begin{frame}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \imgsrc*{Many people contributed to the images in this frame and the next.}
  \end{frame}
  \begin{frame}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  \end{frame}
  \imgsrc*{off}
  \begin{frame}
    \includegraphics[height=.9\textheight]{tiger}

    \imgsrc[Image courtesy]{Somebody}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

You might need to tweak it a bit depending on your theme. The default theme looks like this:

[image: image credits in default theme]

Essentially, the command `\imgsrc{<whatever>}` simply creates an acknowledgement in a smaller font. If the optional argument is not specified, it reads 'Image credit: '. If the argument is specified `\imgsrc[<custom credit>]{}`, it reads ': '.

The starred version of the command puts the credit in the footer of the document indefinitely. To switch the footer off, you can say `\imgsrc*{off}` which will return the footer to the default, empty state.

Comment: Nice to see you're back ...

Answer (score 3):

The `copyrightbox` package is done for that. It defines a `\copyrightbox` command,and lets you place the copyright text on the left, right (default, turned upright) or bottom of the box:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cabin}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption, copyrightbox}
\captionsetup{justification=centering, labelfont=sc, labelsep=endash}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
 \centering
  \copyrightbox[b]{\includegraphics[scale=0.23]{Piero_di_Cosimo_3bis}}{Portrait of Simonetta Vespucci\\Courtesy of Piero di Cosimo}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]